# How/where can I "stash"/keep data in my application?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I display dates to the user in a layout that are let's say are textual.
When the user presses a button I want to get the information in those fields that represent these "dates" but if I get the text in them is not of value to me.
I would need to store somewhere the original dates that created these "textual" elements and fetch them from there.
Is there a specific construct in android that one can use as a stash area or should I just use a static class with variable to hold them?

Comment: Keep them in memory or http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: @madlymad: These seem to be for primitives. While I want to save a `Joda.LocalTime`

Comment: You can use the file system to save almost any object thought java serializable (see **Internal Storage**). Also, I guess there is a way to save your time either as a string or int/long value (see **SharedPreferences**).

Comment: @madlymad:With this approach can I access them from different fragments?

Comment: @Jim Yes, with **Internal Storage** or **SharedPreferences** you can accses them from wherever you want.

Comment: @JonasCz:Does it survice a pause?

Comment: Yes, the data will stay there even if your app is closed or the phone is turned off.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, please do accept it if it worked for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you should use `SharedPreferences` to store the data by converting it into a String (text) or int/long first. 
This will allow you to easily write and retrieve data, and you should use this.

You can also use the file system to save almost any Java object using `serializable`, on Internal Storage.

Either way, the data will stay there even if your app is closed or the device is turned off.

Comment: So if either way the data survive, how would I choose between the SharedPreferences and the filesystem? Are they suited in specific cases?

Comment: SharedPrefernces is easier to use.

Comment: It should be used when you want to save only Text or numbers. With `serializable` , you can save any Java objects.